# Problems Submit Button

Tags: php, html

I'm new to web programing. I'm trying to learn PHP and HTML. I created an Home Page (index.html) with a navigation bar. I put there an href to a form called register_form.php, it goes to the page but after I type all the information and click in the register button, it goes to the source page. I tried to find some answers, searching, but i can't solve the problem. I use a program to send my files and have PHP, it is XAMP. I activated all modules expcept tomcat, because i'm not able.

Register_form.php

```
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" a href="web_style.css"/>
</HEAD>

<div class="caixas">
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br/>
    Email: </br><input type="text" name="email1" /><br/>
    Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br/>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br/>
    <div class="regbut">
        <input class="reg" type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

register.php

```
<?PHP
require('config.php');

$erro = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Sorry, your passwords do not match.");</script>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Verificacao
$email1=$_POST['email1'];
$email2=$_POST['email2'];
$pass1=$_POST['pass1'];
$pass2=$_POST['pass2'];

if($email1==$email2){
    if($pass1==$pass2){
        //Continuar

        $name=mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $lname=mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
        $uname=mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $email1=mysql_escape_string($_POST['email1']);
        $email1=mysql_escape_string($email1);
        $email2=mysql_escape_string($email2);
        $pass1=mysql_escape_string($pass1);
        $pass2=mysql_escape_string($pass2);



        mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_data (name, lname, uname, email, pass) VALUES ('".$name."','".$lname."','".$uname."','".$email1."','".$pass1."')");
        header("Location: index.html");
    }else{

        echo $erro;

        exit();
    }
}else{
    echo 'Sorry, your emails do not match. </br>';
}}
?>
```

If you need more information please tell me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by, "it goes to the source page"?

Comment: When i click on the register button it shows me the code i wrote (register.php)

Comment: Are you sure you're running php on your server?

Comment: I think so, I'm running the following modules: Apache, MySQL, FileZilla and Mercury.

Comment: I didn't PHP in that list. So far it does not seem that you are.

Comment: I took this from my XAMPP status
http://prntscr.com/3b0isa

Comment: Sounds like a possible configuration issue

Comment: Do you know how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that can imagine is that your web pages are not inside `c:\xampp\htdocs\` or you not running your pages from localhost.

So move your files there (if they are not there) and run from localhost (if you not running your webpages from there). Your url should be like this `localhost/path/to/register_form.php` and not like this `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/path/to/register_form.php`

Comment: I created 2 folders inside htdocs, one called files and another called login. All my files are in the login folder. My url appears like this
    file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/files/Login/register_form.php

Comment: Thats why you see the source code. All your files for a particular project must be in the same folder e.g `myproject` then you must type in `localhost/myproject/register_form.php` to go the page

Comment: OHHHHH, I got it! I was clicking in the file on the windows explorer and not typing "http://localhost/files/login/index.html". Thank you!!!!